# How to pass a Variable/Function into SQL Query?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I am attempting to Insert a Row on a Table, but I cannot seem to pass the TASK_ID as a value/variable/function into the SQL Statement. Throughout the application, to acquire TASK_ID, I use:

`Dim taskID = ds.Tables("ReminderTable").Rows(Count).Field(Of Integer)("TASK_ID")`

Some helpful context-code :

`da.Fill(ds, "ReminderTable")`

`Count = ds.Tables("ReminderTable").Rows.Count - 1`

Here is what I'm trying to do:

`da.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO ACTIVITY (TASK_ID, ACTIVITY_CDE, ACTIVITY_NOTE) VALUES (3827, 1, 'Reminder Sent: ' & Now)", Connection)`

I keep receiving the error

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

when I replace **3827** with a variable/function/reference.

The  statement works as-is, but I need to replace "**3827**" in the above statement with the TASK_ID, but it won't accept my variable, a function or the location that I use elsewhere throughout the project to reference the same thing.

I'm working in Visual Studio 2019, using a Microsoft Access Database

Comment: Please edit the question and post the syntax that's failing when you're attempting to concatenate in the variable.

Comment: Embedding a date into a text entry is mixing data. A date value in its own date/time field would be far more useful information. Activity_CDE should explain that activity was a "Reminder Sent".

Comment: ```da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taskID", taskID)```
Parameterized the query, and all seems to be working.

I will take that into consideration @June7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/special-characters/interpolated)

```vb
da.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand(
$"INSERT INTO ACTIVITY (TASK_ID, ACTIVITY_CDE, ACTIVITY_NOTE) 
  VALUES ({taskID}, 1, 'Reminder Sent: ' & Now())", Connection)
```

If getting the date and time from .NET, you would be able to add that with string interpolation as well

```vb
da.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand(
$"INSERT INTO ACTIVITY (TASK_ID, ACTIVITY_CDE, ACTIVITY_NOTE) 
  VALUES ({taskID}, 1, 'Reminder Sent: {DateTime.Now}')", Connection)
```

Comment: Where is the closing apostrophe delimiter following the concatenated date/time value?

Comment: @June7 there needn't be one because the [Now() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_now.asp) is called by Access, not .NET.

Comment: But won't Access expect apostrophe delimiters for text values? Compiled string like: `INSERT …, 'Reminder Sent: 2/3/2020 2:00:00 PM')`

Comment: @June7 Nope. This insert command is perfectly acceptable to Access: `INSERT INTO ACTIVITY (TASK_ID, ACTIVITY_CDE, ACTIVITY_NOTE)   VALUES (3827, 1, 'Reminder Sent: ' & Now())`

Comment: Well, I'll be danged! I have used Now() or Date() functions embedded within SQL string for saving to date/time field but guess I've never had to concatenate date/time with text which I advised OP not to do either.

Comment: Hello SQL injection attack. Never, every just inline values if you have the option to pass in a parameter.

Comment: @JonathanAllen from the Integer taskID? Really?

Comment: And tomorrow when they need to add a string?

Comment: @JonathanAllen no, I'm answering the question above. It's really just about string concatenation.

Comment: The question is "How to pass a Variable/Function into SQL Query?". This is the absolute wrong way to pass a variable into a SQL Query.

Comment: @JonathanAllen right, and in this simple case, it is solved with a simple string interpolation. **Zero risk of SQL Injection here**, contrary to your allegation. Can you identify anything wrong with it other than "what if they want to change it tomorrow?" and "it's just not right!". It just works, with no ill side-effect, to do what it's required to do. I'm sorry you believe everything should be so complex.

Comment: I tried this and it wasn't working for me. I ended up parameterizing the query and that seems to do the trick.

```da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taskID", taskID)```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding the Actual Dimension to your First Line of code Like so:

Dim taskID as Integer = ds.Tables("ReminderTable").Rows(Count).Field(Of Integer)("TASK_ID")

You could also write like this:

Dim taskID as Integer = ds.Tables("ReminderTable").Rows(Count)("TASK_ID")

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I appreciate the help, but it seems like parameterizing was the way to go here.

```da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taskID", taskID)```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a really basic example. It is in C#, but you can easily translate it into VB. The important part is the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`.

```
public int Create(EmployeeClassification classification)
{
    if (classification == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(classification), $"{nameof(classification)} is null.");

    const string sql = @"INSERT INTO EmployeeClassification (EmployeeClassificationName) VALUES(@EmployeeClassificationName )";

    using (var con = OpenConnection())
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeClassificationName", classification.EmployeeClassificationName);
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Source: https://grauenwolf.github.io/DotNet-ORM-Cookbook/SingleModelCrud.htm#ado.net

Comment: If using `parameters` it is best to define the datatype and length and **not** rely on implicit casting. Please don't promote the use of `AddWithValue`...

Comment: What is wrong with ```AddWithValue```? That's what I used to solve my problem :P

Comment: AddWithValue can cause a performance hit when searching because it defaults to `nVarChar` and your column may be `varChar`. The mismatch interferes with indexes. But if that is a concern, you can always override the SQL data type.